# How to initialize twitter bootstrap 2.0 tabs when entire tab element is added to page after initial page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am loading in some HTML into a page via Ajax that includes a new tabbable element.  The only problem is that the tabs don't work because bootstrap has already been initialized.  So I tried the following code that correctly targets the intended ul containing the tabs using jQuery.  The tab isn't initializing, however.

Here is the HTML (loaded into the page after the DOM is initialized, via AJAX):

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-fixes-27" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-final-27" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-orig-27" data-toggle="tab">Thre</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-fixes-27">
      <p>Conten1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-final-27">
      <p>Conten2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-orig-27">
      <p>Conten3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then my javascript:

```
$('.nav-tabs').tab();
```

Seems like from what I read (http://www.mightywebdeveloper.com/coding/bootstrap-2-tabs-jquery-load-content/) that should initialize the tabs, but it doesn't do anything.

The problem is that despite initializing the tabs, nothing happens when I click on them.  Even if I target a specific tab using the .tab('show') and it does show correctly.  Still nothing happens when I click on the tabs.

Also, the tabs seem to work just fine if I add them after the fact with an append (see http://jsfiddle.net/HLj4N/9/ that appends the HTML above to a div after clicking a button).  It appears that someone bootstrap.js has already initialized it when it is added.

Any thoughts on why clicking the tabs is doing nothing?

Comment: As it turns out, the bootstrap.js I was using is modified so that the following had some extra characters in it: [data-xxxxxxx-toggle="tab"] so I just had to make a few changes to the HTML and then it worked.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what exactly you did? Because I am having exactly the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When do you attach the tab? After loading the ajax like below?

```
$.get( baseUrl + 'blabla.html').done(
  $('.nav-tabs').tab();
);
```

Comment: Another trick is to select the tab, for example the first tab

Comment: Yes, after loading the ajax.It's weird... I don't get any errors in the console or anything.

Comment: I tried selecting the tab and showing -- which does display/select the tab (I did the second and last tabs).  But, still clicking does nothing.  For seem reason the click event handler is never initialized .  Any thoughts?

Comment: I have the same problem as @key2starz